# How to access the value that is rendered after decoding in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can i access the year from the json shown below which i fetch from a url and decode using

> obj = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)

The folloowing is the response i get after decode

```
{
  "educations"=>{"_total"=>1, 
                 "values"=>[
                            {"id"=>18234534505, 
                             "schoolName"=>"Test", 
                             "startDate"=>{"year"=>2013}
                            }
                           ]
                }
}
```

How can i access the year? I can able to access the values as

> obj['educations']['values']

and it responds as

```
{"id"=>18234534505, "schoolName"=>"Test", "startDate"=>{"year"=>2013}}
```

but how can i get the year? please help me.

**UPDATE:**

how can i add if condition here?

> obj["educations"]["values"].each do |value|
>
> > @user_education = Education.new("start_date" =>
> >     value['startDate']['year'], "education_id" => value['id'],
> >     "school_name" => value['schoolName'])
>
> end

so here if there is no year then how can i check as you said? and there may also be endDate similar to the startDate so how can i check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access the key as

```
obj["educations"]["values"].first["startDate"]["year"]

# above is answer if there is always one array inside `obj["educations"]["values"]`
```

For multiple arrays's

```
year = []

obj["educations"]["values"].each do |object|
  year << object["startDate"]["year"] if !object["startDate"].blank? and !object["startDate"]["year"].blank?
end
```

#### update :

If you want to add attributes to the

```
@user_education = Education.new
@user_education.start_date = value['startDate']['year'] if !value['startDate'].blank? and !value['startDate']['year'].blank?
@user_education.education_id = value['id'] if !value['id'].blank?
@user_education.school_name = value['schoolName'] if !value['schoolName'].blank?
```

Similarly for any other attribute..

```
obj["educations"]["values"].each do |value|
  @user_education = Education.new("education_id" => value['id'], "school_name" => value['schoolName'])
  @user_education.start_date = value["startDate"]["year"] if !value["startDate"].blank? and !object["startDate"]["year"].blank?
  @user_education.save! #To save the object
end
```